# How to map a web application to the root of a virtualhost?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, mod-jk

I wrote a MVC Servlet + JSP web application and deployed in Apache+Tomcat. I don't call JSP directly, but I use them as view and I call them from the Servlets.

To make it visible in a virtual host, I mapped it using JkMount:

```
JkMount /MyApplication/* ajp13_worker
```

However now to access MyApplication I've to write URLs as

```
http://www.example.com/MyApplication/MyServlet
```

I would like to be able to call MyServlet from the root of my virtualhost such as in:

```
http://www.example.com/MyServlet
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(/MyServlet.*) /MyApplication$1 [passthrough]
```

The passthrough will allow mod_jk to take the request after being processed by mod_rewrite

Comment: thank you, this works, I added a RewriteRule to get to the first servlet: "RewriteRule ^/$ /index [R]", however, when in a servlet I call "response.sendRedirect("my-servlet");", it adds the /MyApplication prefix again. Maybe I should call "response.sendRedirect("/my-servlet");

Comment: I don't know about response.sendRedirect but I suspect it returns a relative URI. Tomcat doesn't know about the RewriteRule. Another option is to deploy your application as ROOT.war with "JkMount /* ajp13_worker" in the apache config. Tomcat will still redirect requests to other applications, but will recognize your servlets in the "/" path.